# Why can't alternate output but always “aa”

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a program that does not alternately output 11, 22, aa as expected, but keeps outputting aa.
When I open the annotation, everything works fine, why？

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        var s string = "aa"

        go func() {
                for {
                        fmt.Println(s)
                        time.Sleep(time.Second)
                }
        }()

        go func() {
                for {
                        s = "11"
                        // time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond)
                }
        }()

        go func() {
                for {
                        s = "22"
                        // time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond)
                }
        }()

        time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
}
```

I tried to output the address of `s` in each goroutine and found that they are the same address.

When I pass the pointer of `s` as an argument to the goroutine, it outputs alternately：

```golang
...
go func(s *string) {
    for {
        *s = "11"
        // time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond)
    }
}(&s)
...
```

Comment: You're modifying and reading s concurrently without synchronization. That's a race condition. The behavior of programs with race conditions is undefined. If you build your program with -race it should crash.

Comment: That being said, even if you protect access to s with, say, a mutex, there is still no reason to expect the output to alternate with every line.

Comment: You need to use channels that not only allow goroutines to exchange data, but also serve to synchronize their operation. One goroutine can write data to a channel and another goroutine can read it.

Comment: To understand @Peter's comment, please see [this talk](https://go.dev/blog/waza-talk) (slides are also available).

Comment: Please also pay attention to the fact that you have tagged your question as `csp` (which supposedly meant Communicating Sequential Processes, but that tag means something else here on SO) but your code actually breaks the major point CSP is making: is that those processes _are communicating_ ;-) Your example blindly overwrites a variable without any attempt at communicating that to other processes (goroutines in Go). Please start with the [Go tour](https://go.dev/tour/) and then proceed [there](https://www.google.com/search?q=concurrency+site%3Ago.dev%2Fblog).